# Importing JoystickView into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-custom-view

I'm trying to import this custom view: https://github.com/zerokol/JoystickView into Android Studio by following these instructions: [Importing a custom view in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637176/importing-a-custom-view-in-android-studio).

So I go File -> New -> Import Module, leave everything as default and import.

I then get this error:

[image]

I clicked the link and updated everything to the latest versions but it still doesn't work.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "jacobpihl.bluetoothcar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

Comment: have a look here at a simmilar issue -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715418/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-22

Comment: @Tasos I looked at that question and updated everything then restarted, still get the error

Comment: put the gradle build code in the Q to have a look

Comment: @Tasos added build.gradle in the Q

Comment: if you look here -- https://github.com/zerokol/JoystickView/blob/master/project.properties  -- target android version is 7  -- so perhaps changing (minSdkVersion 15) to 7 might do the trick

Comment: @Tasos Nope, still getting the same error

Comment: not sure then, it looks like it wants to build with 7, looking at this screenshot -- https://github.com/zerokol/JoystickView  -- after when it says (7º Passo: Click with right button on your project go to PROPERTIES -> ANDROID and the ADD) -- if you dont find a resolution from someone login to github and raise an issue

Comment: hi again, go to github and search (joystick view). looks like there's a few so you may find a more updated one  -- like this one --- https://github.com/clkasd/JoystickView

Answer (score 0):

As it doesn't have any resources, you can just copy the class and put where you want in your project.